# How does the source code gets compiled only by a compiler?

Tags: compiler-specific

My question is, How does a compiler converts the source code, its just a software.
Is there a role of  any hardware or CPU to help compiler to do its job? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Like other software compilers need a CPU to run on. However, I haven't heard of any CPUs with any compiler specific support. For example, `gcc` is just another C++ (was C prior to 2012) program. It can compile and run itself just like any other C++ program, and the CPU runs it just like any other piece of code.

Comment: Thanks, Just wanted to know how a compiler can do parsing  with out the help of hardware